# Sorting a Linked List into alphabetical order

Tags: c++

I am having trouble deleting a node from a sorted linked list. I have read in from a .txt file 73 different names that must be sorted alphabetically. I have a switch statement that is supposed to be able to do 5 separate things to a linked list. At the moment I have gotten number 1 and 2 to work but not three. #3 wants me to be able to delete a name from the linked list. After I type the name I want to delete, my code will not display anything. Therefore I am assuming I am having an issue with the deleteAfter function. Can anyone give me a hint on why this may be?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct node{
    string name;
    node *next;
};

node *A = NULL;

void addnode(string newname){
    node *add,
         *last,
         *current;

    add = new node;
    add->name = newname;

    if (A == NULL){
        add->next = A;
        A = add;
    }else{
        current = A;
        last    = A;
        while (current && current->name < newname){
            last = current;
            current = current->next;
        }

        if (current == A){
            /* Insert before 1st node */
            add->next = A;
            A = add;
        }
        else{
            /* Insert between last and current 
               or at the end of the list */
            last->next = add;
            add->next = current;
        }
    }
}
void deleteName(string name)
{
    node *curr;
    node *nextNode;
    curr = A;
    nextNode = curr;
    while(curr){
        if(curr -> next -> name == name){
            nextNode = curr -> next;
            curr -> next = nextNode -> next;
        }

    }


}



void display()
{
    node *curr;
    curr = A;
     while(curr){
        if(A == NULL){break;}
        cout << A->name << endl;
        A = A->next;
    }

}

int main(){


    int input, count;
    count = 0;
    ifstream dataFile;
    dataFile.open("Data.txt");
    string item;
    string name;
    while(dataFile)
    {
        dataFile >> item;
        addnode(item);
        count++;
    }




    cout << "1. Display the linked list\n";
    cout << "2. Display the length of the list\n";
    cout << "3. Delete name from the list\n";
    cout << "4. display the length of a section of the list\n";
    cout << "5. Print out section of list\n";
    cin >> input;

    switch (input)
    {
    case 1:
        display();
        break;
    case 2:
        cout << "There are " << count - 1 << " names in the list\n";
        break;
    case 3:
        cout << "Type in the name that you want to be deleted: ";
        cin >> name;
        deleteName(name);
        display();
        break;
    case 4:
        break;
    case 5:
        break;
    }


    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;

}
```

This is the code that I have so far. You will notice that in my main function I read input from a file called "Data.txt".

```
joe
bob
harry
mary
brian
tom
jerry
bullwinkle
pam
ellis
dale
bill
barrack
george
gertrude
zack
zeus
apollo
gemini
greg
larry
meriam
webster
thomas
stewart
dianna
theresa
billyjoe
carl
karl
charles
karla
donna
tena
kerry
howard
johnson
ulyssess
paul
peter
issaac
marvin
dudz
chuck
ellie
anny
judy
matt
ross
dan
robert
kim
eric
junkun
ghassan
cris
raymond
avery
roy
halley
mitzee
ziggy
rocky
twirly
max
huey
dewy
hongkongfooey
clarence
lala
sammy
fred
francis
```

This is what the txt document consists of^^. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What I'd like to know is where everyone keeps getting taught to use `system("pause")`...

Comment: The usage of pointers is not done properly I'm afraid. When using pointers you are supposed to deal with *creation* and *deletion*. I don't see deletion in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing next without checking that it isn't null, and you aren't iterating through the list. Plus you should break after you've found it (unless you want to delete all instances and you should delete the node, as you will be leaking memory. Also, you won't be able to remove the very first element, as you never check it. You could add in a specific check for it as you need to handle changing the root node.

```
if (A != nullptr && A->name == name)
{
    node *toBeDeleted = A;
    A = A->next;
    delete toBeDeleted;
    return;
}

while(curr && curr->next){
    if(curr->next->name == name){
        nextNode = curr->next;
        curr->next = nextNode->next;
        delete nextNode;
        break;
    }
    curr = curr->next;
}
```

Of course if you want to delete all instances of the name, you need to remove the return and break statements.

Your display function will also empty the list. You need to set curr, not A:

```
void display()
{
    node *curr;
    curr = A;
    while(curr){
       cout << curr->name << endl;
       curr = curr->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.! You are right, I wasn't checking if next equals null.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (current && strcmp(current->name , newname) <=0){
    last = current;
    current = current->next;
}
```

Try this.

Comment: Infinite loop. The OP is using a cycle in the linked list.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a linked list data structure. What I found strange is that you use a cycle. The last node's next element points to the beginning again.

Here is the `deleteName` I propose according to your level of knowledge and style (that I believe to see):

```
void deleteName(string name) {

    node *current = A;
    node *previous;

    while (current) {
        if (current->name == name) {
            previous->next = current->next;
            delete current;
            break;
        } else {
            previous = current;
            current = current->next;
        }
    }
}
```